# Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a PersonView like following

```
struct PersonView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    let text: Text
    let detailText: Text
    var content: (() -> Content)? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            text
            detailText
            content?()
        }
    }
}
```

Also My sample model looks like:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

To make life easy I have made an extension of **PersonView**

```
extension PersonView {
    init<Content: View>(person: Person, content: (() -> Content)? = nil) {
        self.init(text: Text(person.name),
                  detailText: Text("\(person.age)"), content: content)
    }
}
```

but here I am getting error like 
***"Cannot convert value of type '(() -> Content)?' to expected argument type 'Optional<(() -> _)>'"***

I am not sure where I am getting wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not declare an extra generic parameter `Content` in the initialiser. The initialiser should not be generic, and instead just use the `Content` generic parameter from `PersonView`:

```
extension PersonView {
    init(person: Person, content: (() -> Content)? = nil) {
        self.init(text: Text(person.name),
                  detailText: Text("\(person.age)"), content: content)
    }
}
```

The extra `Content` that you declared is a *different* generic parameter from the `Content` in `PersonView<Content>`, which is why the compiler says it can't convert the types.

Comment: But I want to make my code much simpler and want to  set my `Content` inside the **init** method manually and try to implement the `init` function without  `content: (() -> Content)?`, I am getting this error **Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred**.


Like I just want to to keep my `init` method like `init(person: Person)` and will assign the `Content` inside it according to `Person` properties.

Comment: @Evana What kind of `Content` are you trying to assign to it? For example, if it is a `Text`, you need the extension to only apply to `PersonView where Content == Text`. Anyway, that seems to be unrelated to this question. I suggest you ask a new one.